# How to know the state of an sql instance in a c# program

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one database with one mirror in high-safety mode (using a witness server at the moment but planing to take him out), this database will be used to store data gathered by a c# program.

I want to know how can I check in my program the state of all the SQL instances and to cause/force a manual failover.

is there any c# API to help me with this?

**info:** im using sql server 2008

**edit:** I know I can query sys.database_mirroring but for this I need the principal database up and runing, I would like to contact each sql instance and check their status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after playing around a bit I found this solution (i'm not if this is a proper solution, so leave comments plz)

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi;

ManagedComputer mc = new ManagedComputer("localhost");
foreach (Service svc in mc.Services) {
    if (svc.Name == "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"){
        textSTW.Text = svc.ServiceState.ToString();
    }
    if (svc.Name == "MSSQL$TESTSERVER"){
        textST1.Text = svc.ServiceState.ToString();
    }
    if (svc.Name == "MSSQL$TESTSERVER3") {
        textST2.Text = svc.ServiceState.ToString();
    }
}
```

this way i'm just looking for the state of the services (Running/Stoped) and is much faster, am I missing something?

Comment: i've found a limitation in the solution...it only works for local instances...for remote instances we need to do something else to have access to the services.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

> SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) is a collection of objects that are designed for programming all aspects of managing Microsoft SQL Server. SQL Server Replication Management Objects (RMO) is a collection of objects that encapsulates SQL Server replication management.

I have used SMO in managed applications before - works a treat.

---

To find out the state of an instance, use the [`Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) object - is has a `State` and a `Status` properties.

Comment: for some reason state is always "Existing" and status "Offline"
and I cant see status if the sql server instance is actually down ,because it throws an exception. (and I wouldn't mind with this behaviour...but it takes about 5 seconds to throw it instead of doing it immediately)

any ideas about why is this happening? or how can I see properly if one server is down or not?

Comment: @RagnaRock - It stands to reason that if SMO can't connect to the instance that it will throw.

Comment: but is there a faster way to detect if the server is down? waiting 5 seconds for a failure, seems too long for me.

a special method to detect this kind of error or something...

Comment: @RagnaRock - Why do you need this to be faster? How many instances are you checking?

Comment: only one...but feels unnatural to me to take this long to check for connectivity, I thought there would be a more appropriate and faster way